# Inline Editing not working in Kendo Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I have a Grid as below. If I use the Grid in regular page, It is working fine. The same Grid I used in Kendo Window. When I click on Edit, Grid row is changing to Editable mode. After changing and Click on Update, controller is not getting fired and Grid is still in Editable mode. How Can I fire controller from Kendo WIndow ?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("ZipGrid")
.Columns(columns =>{
columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden();
columns.Bound(p => p.ZipCode).Width(250);
columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.ToolBar(toolBar =>{toolBar.Create().Text("Add Zip Code");}).Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
.Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
.Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
.Create(create => create.Action("AddZipCode", "Manage"))
.Read(read => read.Action("GetZipCode", "Manage"))
.Update(update => update.Action("UpdateZipCode", "Manage"))
.Destroy(Destroy => Destroy.Action("AddZipCode", 
"Manage")).ServerOperation(false)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are just calling the controller method without sending any data `update.Action("UpdateZipCode", "Manage", new { zipcode = "new zipcode" })` If you just call the method without the signature it expects it's not going to work and probably not sending back a success message to tell the grid to update.

Edit**
Look at the controller for "UpdateZipCode" and see what it's expecting I guessed and said a value called zipcode if it's more you need to specify that in the update action